# First wait for time.AfterFunc then start time.NewTicker

Tags: go

I am trying to set up a service routine that runs every hour on the hour. It seems to me that either of those two are easy. To run my routine on the hour I can use `time.AfterFunc()`, first calculating the remaining time until the top of the hour. And to run my routine every hour I can use `time.NewTicker()`.

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to start the `NewTicker` only after the function passed to  `AfterFunc()` has fired.

My `main()` function looks something like this:

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("starting up")

    // Here I'm setting up all kinds of HTTP listeners and gRPC listeners, none
    // of which is important, save to mention that the app has more happening
    // than just this service routine.

    // Calculate duration until next hour and call time.AfterFunc()
    // For the purposes of this exercise I'm just using 5 seconds so as not to
    // have to wait increments of hours to see the results
    time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 5, func() {
        fmt.Println("AfterFunc")
    })

    // Set up a ticker to run every hour. Again, for the purposes of this
    // exercise I'm ticking every 2 seconds just to see some results
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
    defer t.Stop()
    go func() {
        for now := range t.C {
            fmt.Println("Ticker")
        }
    }()

    // Block until termination signal is received
    osSignals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(osSignals, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)
    <-osSignals

    fmt.Println("exiting gracefully")
}
```

Of course `time.AfterFunc()` is blocking and the payload of my `Ticker` is deliberately put in a go routine so it also won't be blocking. This is so that my HTTP and gRPC listeners can continue to listen but also to allow the block of code at the end of `main()` to exit gracefully upon a termination signal from the OS. But the obvious downside now is that the `Ticker` kicks off pretty much immediately and fires twice (2 second intervals) before the function passed to `AfterFunc()` fires. The output looks like this:

```
Ticker
Ticker
AfterFunc
Ticker
Ticker
Ticker
etc.
```

What I wanted of course is:

```
AfterFunc
Ticker
Ticker
Ticker
Ticker
Ticker
etc.
```

The following also doesn't work and I'm not exactly sure why. It prints AfterFunc but the Ticker never fires.

```golang
time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 5, func() {
        fmt.Println("AfterFunc")

        t := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
        defer t.Stop()
        go func() {
            for now := range t.C {
                fmt.Println("Ticker")
            }
        }()
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```golang
time.AfterFunc(time.Second*5, func() {
        fmt.Println("AfterFunc")

        t := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
        defer t.Stop()
        for range t.C {
            fmt.Println("Ticker")
        }
    })
```

It produces the output you need:

```
starting up
AfterFunc
Ticker
Ticker
Ticker
Ticker
Ticker
```

Comment: No it does not. This is exactly what I had in my original question. The implicit function you specify for AfterFunc exits and executes t.Stop() immediately after setting up the ticker. So the ticker will never get the opportunity to fire.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you execute my code? This `t.Stop()` is **deferred** so it will be executed only at the end of the function, right after the `for range` loop for the ticker.

Comment: @DewaldSwanepoel You had the same code enveloped into a goroutine. The program stopped the ticker right after the goroutine had started. That's why you had your `defer` executed before the ticker. But in my code, everything is in the same goroutine and works as it should.

Comment: Apologies @zergon321, I only realise now that your sample does not wrap the ticker in a goroutine, which is the key difference.

Comment: I feel like a right knob now for downvoting your answer and SO prevents me from changing my vote unless the answer is edited. If you edit the answer, maybe just add explicitly that the ticker loop is not wrapped in a goroutine, I can change my vote.

Answer (score 3):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.google.cn/ref/spec)
>
> [Program execution](https://golang.google.cn/ref/spec#Program_execution)
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then
>   invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to
>   complete.

```
time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 5, func() {
    fmt.Println("AfterFunc")
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
    defer t.Stop()
    go func() {
        for now := range t.C {
            fmt.Println("Ticker")
        }
    }()
})
```

`defer t.Stop()` stops the ticker.

You are not waiting for the goroutine to run.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I figured that out shortly after I posted. The function passed to AfterFunc only fires once and then exits, at which point the Ticker is stopped seeing as defer t.Stop() occurs in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Gosh, I figured it out not long after posting, though I still think my solution lacks some elegance.

As @peterSO pointed out, the function passed to `AfterFunc()` executes and stops the `Ticker` moments after creating it with `defer t.Stop()`

The solution for me was to define the `t` variable before the call to `AfterFunc()` so that it has scope outside of the `AfterFunc()` payload function, and then stop it at the end of my `main()` func. Here is the new `main()` func:

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("starting up")

    var t *time.Ticker
    time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 5, func() {
        fmt.Println("AfterFunc")

        t = time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
        go func() {
            for now := range t.C {
                fmt.Println("Ticker")
            }
        }()
    })
    //defer t.Stop()

    // Block until termination signal is received
    osSignals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(osSignals, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)
    <-osSignals

    t.Stop()

    logger.Info("exiting gracefully")
}
```

Strangely though that commented out `defer t.Stop()` causes a panic (invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference) when the application closes upon a termination signal. If I stop it as in the uncommented `t.Stop()` at the very end of the code, it works as expected. Not sure why that is.

Comment: There is no reason or point to use a goroutine like this inside of the function given to `time.AfterFunc`; it just complicates things. See [zergon321's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57543802/55504) without a separate goroutine.